# Puppet hosts pull every 30 minutes?

Tags: unix, manifest, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Is it 30 minutes from the last change?
I made change in master and the changes were applied in my hosts one by one, not together. There was difference of few minutes. So I assume Puppet hosts pull every 30 minutes after they pulled last time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the default configuration for the puppet agent in daemon mode.

But you can change the update period in file`/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`

```
runinterval=xxx
```

or you can run the agent one time with `puppet agent --onetime` and use `cron` to have agent runs synchronized, so you can have catalog changes applied at 02:00 AM

Comment: If you *do* use cron, realize that every node hitting the master at the same time will result in many of them timing out in a large environment.